# Parallelism with Streams created from Iterators

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Experimenting with streams I ran into the following behavior which I don't quite understand. I created a parallel stream from an iterator and I noticed that it did not seem to be exhibiting parallelism. In the below example I've printed a counter to the console for two parallel streams, one created from an iterator and the other from a list. The stream created from the list exhibited the behavior I expected which was to print the counter in non-sequential order but the stream created from the iterator printed the counter in sequential order. Am I creating the parallel stream from an iterator incorrectly?

```
    private static int counter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lstr = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Iterator<Integer> iter = lstr.iterator();

    System.out.println("Iterator Stream: ");
    StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iter, Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.CONCURRENT), true).forEach(i -> {
        System.out.print(counter + " ");
        counter++;
    });

    counter = 0;
    System.out.println("\nList Stream: ");
    lstr.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
        System.out.print(counter + " ");
        counter++;
    });

}
```

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner even a stream constructed from an `Iterator` supports parallelism, though quiet limited.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner That's not true. Have a look at the implementation of `trySplit` in `java.util.Spliterators.IteratorSpliterator`.

Answer (score 11):

There is no guaranty that parallel processing prints the counter in non-sequential order. Further, since you’re updating a variable without synchronization, it’s possible to miss updates made by other threads, so the results may be entirely inconsistent.

Besides that, an `Iterator` has to be polled sequentially, so to get at least some gain from parallel processing, elements have to be buffered, but without a known size, there is no good estimate on how many elements to buffer. The default strategy uses more than thousand elements and does not split the work well.

So if you use more than thousand elements you might notice more parallel activity. Alternatively, you may specify a size using `StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(iter, lstr.size(), 0), true)` to construct the stream. Then, the internally used buffering will be adapted.

Still, the `List`’s stream will have a more efficient parallel processing, as it not only knows its size but supports splitting the workload utilizing the random access nature of the underlying data structure.

Comment: dont they all start from 1024 and increase by doubling their size? On the phone, cant look at the sources right now :(

Comment: @Eugene `AbstractSpliterator` will split off `1024` elements the first time, increasing the batch size by `1024` each time until reaching 2²⁵. If you have fewer than 1000 elements, all of them end up in the first array. The problem is that the now-empty spliterator still reports “unknow size” but the stream implementation treats “unknow size” as the literal `Long.MAX_VALUE`, so instead of splitting the less-than-thousand element array, it keeps trying to split the actually empty 〈“unknow size”/`Long.MAX_VALUE`〉 spliterator. Having a size estimate causes it to do reasonable splitting.

Comment: `IteratorSpliterator` does the same as `AbstractSpliterator`, but duplicates the code instead of inheriting it.

Comment: actually changing from spliteratorUnknownSize to fixed size makes it parallelly processable and you can check it in the logs which "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7" is processing currently

Answer (score 9):

The current implementation will try to parallelize a stream produced form an iterator by buffering up the values and dispatching them to several threads but it only kicks in if the stream is long enough.  Increase your list to 10000 elements and you should see parallelism.

With a large list, it might be easier to see how elements distributed by thread if you collect into a map grouped by thread.  Replace your `.forEach` with `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> Thread.currentThread().getName(), Collectors.counting()))`

Answer (score 9):

There was a flaw in `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize()` implementation. I fixed it in Java 19, see [JDK-8280915](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8280915). Since 19-ea+19-1283 early access build the problem is not reproduced anymore, `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize` is parallelized correctly. Here's the output on my machine:

```
Iterator Stream: 
0 0 0 1 0 0 6 7 8 0 0 0 0 12 0 15 0 17 18 10 20 21 22 23 11 0 5 27 28 29 30 0 31 32 3 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 4 0 2 45 45 43 34 33 26 25 24 54 19 56 16 0 59 59 0 62 14 13 13 65 64 63 61 60 57 71 73 73 75 76 55 54 79 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 85 84 80 74 70 70 68 67 66 94 92 88 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is custom implementation with desired behavior.

Fork each element (unlike `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize`) progressively (there is only single unprocessed `ForkJoinTask` in the work queue when worker pool is saturated).
There is only single thread which `trySplit` at any point of time hence there is no atomicy implication for `Iterator.hasNext` and `Iterator.next` and concurrent thread safetiness of the iterator implementation.
There should be at least one element on the beginning.

**Usage**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(IntStream.range(0, 10).iterator(), Spliterator.CONCURRENT), true).forEach(SpliteratorTest::process);
    out.println("---");
    stream(new ForkNextSpliterator<>(IntStream.range(0, 10).iterator()), true).forEach(SpliteratorTest::process);
}

private static void process(Integer i) {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos((int) (Math.random() * 100)));
    out.println(i + "\t" + currentThread().getName());
}
```

**Output**

```
0   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
1   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
2   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
3   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
4   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
5   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
6   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
7   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
8   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
9   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
---
5   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13
4   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4
0   main
2   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2
7   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15
6   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6
1   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9
3   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11
9   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
8   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-8
```

**Implementation**

```
import static java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE;
import static java.util.stream.Stream.empty;
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;

public class ForkNextSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    public static <T> Stream<T> parallelStream(Iterable<T> iterable) {
        Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
        return iterator.hasNext() ? stream(new ForkNextSpliterator<>(iterator), true) : empty();
    }

    private final Iterator<T> iter;
    private final T value;
    private boolean split;

    public ForkNextSpliterator(Iterator<T> iter) {
        this.value = iter.next();
        this.iter = iter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        action.accept(value);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return (split ^= true) && iter.hasNext()
                ? new ForkNextSpliterator<>(iter)
                : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return CONCURRENT;
    }
}
```